# logrotate program still looking for deleted configuration

Tags: linux, logrotate

I removed a custom logrotate configuration within the /etc/logrotate.d/ directory  since it was no longer needed, and it appears it is still trying to process that previous configuration becuase I am getting emails from the servers stating the following:

```
error: cannot stat /etc/logrotate.d/process: No such file or directory
```

The man pages for logrotate do not mentioned the process for deleting the configurations, just how to create them. Since there is no logrotate daemon to restart, would anyone know why its still trying to execute the previous non-existing configuration?

Comment: The process to delete this program isn't explain cos is a default program installed with linux installation. This program is needed to make a rotate and compress the logs run both with cron and if you don't needed you have too delete "cron" calls and check files crons to delete the line who call logrotate in the cron directory as /etc/cron.daily   ... month ....

Comment: Sigh. You were right. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome i hope that help, regards.